how to show public images on laravel 11 with inertia and react
I'm uploading images via a form using laravel 11 and react with inertia, the images are being stored here (I'm using Windows) C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\storage\app\public\product_images
for example:
C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\storage\app\public\product_images\gibson-lp-classic-20240717001924.png
been trying to show a small thumbnail of the image on the edit page, but it just doesn't show:
<div className="mt-4">
  {images.map((image, index) => (
    <div
      key={image.id || index}
      className="flex items-center justify-between mb-2"
    >
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <img
          src={
            image.url ||
            (image instanceof File || image instanceof Blob
              ? URL.createObjectURL(image)
              : '')
          }
          alt={image.name || 'Image'}
          className="w-16 h-16 object-cover mr-4"
        />
      </div>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="text-red-500 hover:text-red-700 focus:outline-none"
        onClick={() => handleImageRemove(index)}
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
{errors.length > 0 && (
  <div className="mt-4 text-red-600">
    {errors.map((error, index) => (
      <div key={index}>{error}</div>
    ))}
  </div>
)}

I want to show the images that are already stored, but can't seem to access any image via the browser or through react, the filesystems.php is intact, I haven't touched it.
is there someone who can point me in the right direction regarding this?
thanks!

So, you uploaded some images from the app and now you want to get them back and display them, right?

Yes. Thats what i need

How to you store the path of the image? Save each image in model (e.g $model->img_url) or save the directory in model? (e.g $model->img_directory) (2nd option where you can store multiple images related to model, but you cannot fetch a specific image). Depending on the use case, the answer will be different

Make sure that the path you saved is correct and valid (does not return 404)

Laravel uses a symbolic link to access the files in the storage/app/public directory via the public/storage URL. Ensure you have created this symbolic link by running the following Artisan command:
php artisan storage:link
Then you can send the url to your component with Inertia, just change the below to suit your application.
$product = Product::find($id);
$imagePath = asset('storage/product_images/' . $product->image_url);

return Inertia::render('Product/Edit', [
  'product' => $product,
  'imagePath' => $imagePath,
]);

Then output in React:
{imagePath && (
  <div>
    <img src={imagePath} alt={product.name} />
  </div>
)}

